# Ant apache NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, xml, ant, javac

I am having some problems when I build the file build.xml. I know it some problem with the class path of the tag javac, but i don't know how to solve it.

```
[java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/core/Response
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2521)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2764)
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1653)
 [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
 [java]     at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.Response
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
 [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
 [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

The library of my project is in the "/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/", and this is my file "build.xml":

```
<property name="src" value="\${basedir}/src" />  
<property name="build" value="classes" />  
<property name="dist" value="dist" />  
<property name="package" value="*" />  

<target name="init">  
<echo> Criando os diretorio classes, doc e dist.</echo>  
<mkdir dir="..\${build}" />  
<mkdir dir="..\${dist}" />  
</target> 

<target name="compile" depends="init" >  
<echo> Compilando o projeto.</echo>  
<javac srcdir="\${src}" destdir="..\${build}" includeantruntime="false">
    <classpath>
    <fileset dir="\${basedir}/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/">
       <include name="jersey-server-1.4.jar" />
    </fileset>
  </classpath> 
</javac>
</target>  

<target name="dist" depends="compile">  
<echo> Gerando o .jar do projeto.</echo>      
<jar jarfile="..\${dist}/InfosoundWebApp.jar" basedir="..\${build}">  
    <!-- Tornando o jar executável-->  
    <manifest>  
        <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.informatec.restfull.ServerRestfull"/>             
    </manifest>  
</jar>  
</target>  

<target name="all" depends="dist">  
<echo> Executa o projeto.</echo>  
<java jar="..\${dist}/InfosoundWebApp.jar" fork="true" />
</target>  

<target name="clear">  
    <delete dir="..\${build}" />  
    <delete dir="..\${dist}" />      
</target>
```

If someone can help me, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to run the JavaEE app from JavaSE.
The class javax/ws/rs/core/Response is only available under JavaEE (on your webserver).
Your build.xml target="all" tries to execute your webapp under JavaSE.  Get rid of it.  Make target="dist" the default target and then upload your jar to your webserver (Tomat, etc.).

Comment: Hi, tks for the answer. Do you know how can I structure the target "compile" to import the libraries?

Comment: You should not need to import the libraries.  The classpath will allow your java files to compile.  Then dist makes your jar, which should be a WAR file.  I think you need to research on how to create a JavaEE package, not a standard JAR file.  A WAR file is uploaded to the webserver and it runs it.  You don't run it from java command line.